# XAML Restricting visibility of styles from merged ResourceDictionaries

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I'm working on a WPF application, which uses styles stored in many resource dictionaries, referenced in App.xaml and I have been struggling with restricting visibility of styles used internally, to build templates of controls.

Let's say that I have a `ResourceDictionary` called `ButtonStyles` which contains the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonInternalStyles.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource SomeInternalStyle}">
    <!--Setters-->
</Style>
```

I also have a second `ResourceDictionary` called `ButtonInternalStyles`, which contains:

```
<Style x:Key="SomeInternalStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <!--Setters-->
</Style>
```

My App.xaml references only `ButtonStyles` `ResourceDictionary`, but I can use `SomeInternalStyle` in my Views, which I don't want to be able to do.

**Is there a way to restrict a visibility of `ButtonInternalStyles`, so I can use it only in `ButtonStyles`?**

Comment: Sorry, I made some edits just now, to make it easier to understand. I want to restrict a visibility of some ResourceDictionaries, so that other developers don't use styles that they shouldn't be using, to force more consistency in the application. Styles in ButtonInternalStyles should be for internal use, only in another ResourceDictionaries.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time Kacper, I had foolishly tested my answer only against the designer and the compiler. It fails at runtime, exactly as you report.

Comment: It's OK, I appreciate that you tried to help me

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to restrict a visibility of ButtonInternalStyles, so I can use it only in ButtonStyles?

No, I don't think you can do this. All resources defined in a `ResourceDictionary` that is merged into another `ResourceDictionary` that is indeed in scope, will also be in scope. That's how resource dictionaries work.

I don't really see the problem though. If you want to prevent a consumer of your `ResourceDictionary` from accidentally using your "internal" style, you might give it some name that is hard to guess, e.g.:

```
<Style x:Key="ffdsghdfsgh" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
...
```

Of course this won't help if you use some tool for Visual Studio that provides IntelliSense support and I think you're better of not changing the names of your styles. It's not worth the effort.

Comment: Would you want to maintain a code written like this? Also it would still show in the IntelliSense, so that doesn't help in my case.

Comment: Well, the last sentence was just a suggestion. The answer to your question is: no.

Comment: I though about naming adding some prefixes or suffixes in styles names myself, but that's not really an elegant solution... The application that I'm working on has a lot of explicitly defined styles and I don't want other devs to scroll through IntelliSense thinking over which style to use and why is there so many of them

Comment: So keep it as-is. There is no such thing as "internal" or "protected" styles.